# why are my wifi networks not showing in windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm using a PC that has an external WiFi adapter it was working fine suddenly my WiFi icon doesn't appear and in the settings it is showing me that I have no WiFi.

While in the WiFi adapter software I can see my WiFi networks and I can use them.

No WiFi icon:

[image]

No wifi networks:

[image]

Wifi software:

[image]

Windows 10 showing me that I'm not connected to any WiFi:

[image]

Comment: So what happens when you click "Troubleshoot"?

Comment: @DavidPostill it doesn't do anything just reset my network

Comment: Clearly your TP-Link is **not** "The Reliable Choice" :)

Comment: May be someone applied a filter to blacklist a certain ssid? Ref: [How to Hide Neighborhood Wireless Networks (SSID) on Your Computer?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/hide-neighborhood-wifi-ssid-computer/) | See also [Computer that has VPN software installed can't detect wireless network after upgrading to Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3084164/computer-that-has-vpn-software-installed-can-t-detect-wireless-network)

Comment: I'd assume there has been some update which has removed/reinstalled an incompatible driver. Go get the correct driver for your unit with the OS, and see if a reinstall works :)